# spring-data-jpa:entity attribute as function parameter within a SPEL expression

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-el

In my Kotlin code:

I have an entity class as follows (simplified):

```
@Entity
data class Person(
) {
  @Id val id: String,
  val phoneNumber: String
}
```

I have a spring-data-jpa repository as follows (simplified):

```
interface PersonRepository: JpaRepository<Person, String> {
    @Query(
    value = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE :#T(com.xyz.PhoneUtils).normalizePhoneNumber(p.phoneNumber)} IN :phoneNumbers")
    fun getPersonsByPhoneNumbers(phoneNumbers: Set<String>: Set<Person>): List<Person>
}
```

Notice the use of an SPEL expression to call a static function on specified class. The function normalizes phone numbers to a standard E.164 phone number format. The reason for this complexity is that the Person records may contain phone numbers in non-standard formats but the supplied phoneNumbers via query param phoneNumbers are normalized. To make a comparison I need to normalize the entity attribute phoneNumber within the @Query query expression.

However, I cannot figure out how to use an entity attribute *phoneNumber* as a function param for the *PhoneUtils.normalizePhoneNumber* within the SPEL expression. Spring documentation says nothing about using entity attributes within SPEL expressions though it does say how to use query parameters within the SPEL expression.

Is it possible to use entity attribute as a function param within the SPEL expression? If so, how? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that since JPQL query is mapped to an SQL query the only way to use a function with an entity attribute as parameter is to have the query be invoked by the database. The solution requires calling Kotlin/Java static method using database-specific methods. For my HSQLDB the following describes how it can be done:

https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_jrt_static_methods